# Why I shouldn't use "Repeatable Read" with locking reading (select..for update)"?

Tags: mysql, deadlock, read-committed

In the Mysql Document: "https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-deadlocks-handling.html"

It mentioned: "**If you use locking reads (SELECT ... FOR UPDATE or SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE), try using a lower isolation level such as READ COMMITTED.**"

Could someone tell me why I can't use "Repeatable Read"? Example will be good.

Cheers

Comment: No, it's not the same, I want to know why I can't use "Repeatable Read" with "select .... for update".

Comment: Please [edit] your question for that, cheers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

InnoDB avoids using certain kinds of locks if you use read-committed. This can help you avoid a deadlock.

I designed a whole presentation about this: [InnoDB Locking Explained with Stick Figures](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/innodb-locking-explained-with-stick-figures).

But you'll practically never be able to avoid 100% cases of deadlocks. They're not a mistake, they're a natural part of concurrent systems. You can reduce how frequently deadlocks occur, but you might as well get used to getting some. Design your code to catch exceptions and retry database operations when they get a deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that if record doesn't exist in the table it looks like `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` acquires [next-key lock](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/glossary.html#glos_next_key_lock) in shared mode (or something similar - it's not documented anywhere) for an index record following a non-existent record when `REPEATABLE READ` isolation mode is active.

Let's try an example for a simple table `t` that is empty in `REPEATABLE READ` isolation mode.

```sql
t1> SELECT * FROM t WHERE id = 1 FOR UPDATE;
    no rows found, next-key lock acquired in shared mode
t2> SELECT * FROM t WHERE id = 1 FOR UPDATE;
    no rows found, next-key lock acquired in shared mode
t1> INSERT INTO t (id) VALUES (1);
    transaction t1 is blocked by t2
t2> INSERT INTO t (id) VALUES (1);
    transaction t2 is blocked by t1 - deadlock
```

The deadlock will happen even if the second SELECT and INSERT will use  `id=2` because it also falls into the same gap, locked by `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`, executed in `t1`. And if the table is empty this gap is **infinity**. If the table is not empty the probability of deadlock is smaller for inserting different records, but is still big (it depends on how many gaps in the table and how often you insert to the end of the table - the largest gap).

This happens because `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` from `t1` and `t2` **doesn't block each other when record doesn't exist**. For existent record it acquires the X (exclusive) lock on the record in `t1`, so `t2` will be blocked until `t1` is committed or rolled back. But if the record doesn't exist - it acquires the S (shared) next-key lock on the gap (I'm not sure that it is really an S lock (it is not documented anywhere), but how else MySQL allows to acquire 2 locks concurrently on the same gap?). And this is the main reason of deadlock here - both `t1` and `t2` trying to acquire the IX (insert intention) lock on the gap and then X lock on the inserted record, but both waiting each other because of the lock, acquired by `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`.

This problem doesn't exist when `READ COMMITED` transaction isolation level is used. `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` doesn't hold any locks if record is not found and `READ COMMITED` isolation level is used. So the first `INSERT` will succeed. The second `INSERT` will be blocked by EXCLUSIVE lock acquired by first `INSERT` and after `t1` will be commited, the second `INSERT` will just throw `Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'`.

You could think now that this situation is not better that deadlock. Just another error. But now imagine that second `INSERT` tries to insert a record with `id=2`. In this case it will not be blocked by `t1` and both transactions will succeed. And this is a **big difference** for some applications.